# How to reduce the with of GridViewItems

Tags: flutter, dart

**Example:**

[image]

I want to reduce the width of this picture with childAspectRatio without knowing the values. The image above shows my layout. Is there a way to reduce the with of the GridViewItems, when I am not having the exact values of for using the child-aspect ratio properly?

**Here is my code:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

logger("width => $width");
logger("height => $height");

return GridView.count(
  childAspectRatio: .9/.2,
  // childAspectRatio: 6,
  // padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 250),
  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  crossAxisSpacing: 25,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  crossAxisCount: width <  1510
      ?  2
      : width <  1537
          ?  3
          : 1,
  children: <Widget>[ 
        SelectCargoDropDown(), 
        CargoCampaignDropDown(), 
        FreeCargoNumberField(), 
        IdSelectionDropDown(), 
        AuthSellingDropDown(), 
        PharmacyReferenceDropDown(), 
        InformationPersonReferenceDropDown(),
],);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful to insert your `GridView.count` in an `Expanded` widget.

Then it will automatically take the suitable width for the screen, even it's the same widget in the screen's width or there is another.